# LinAlgError: Singular matrix error while building logistic regression model with p-values

Tags: python-3.x, logistic-regression

I'm using the below function to calculate p-value to build fit logistic regression model.
But I get *LinAlgError: Singular matrix error*.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import scipy.stats as stat

class LogisticRegression_with_p_values:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.model = linear_model.LogisticRegression(*args, **kwargs)
    def fit(self, X, y):
      self.model.fit(X, y)
      denom = (2.0 * (1.0 + np.cosh(self.model.decision_function(X))))
      denom = np.tile(denom, (X.shape[1],1)).T
      F_ij = np.dot((X/denom).T,X)
      Cramer_Rao = np.linalg.inv(F_ij)
      sigma_estimates = np.sqrt(np.diagonal(Cramer_Rao))
      z_scores = self.model.coef_[0] / sigma_estimates
      p_values = [stat.norm.sf(abs(x)) * 2 for x in z_scores]
      self.coef_ = self.model.coef_
      self.intercept_ = self.model.intercept_
      self.p_values = p_values
reg = LogisticRegression_with_p_values()
reg.fit(inputs_train, loan_data_targets_train)
```

PS: Two data sets (inputs_train, loan_data_targets_train) are different.
But, still I get *LinAlgError: Singular matrix error*.
Please help.

Comment: [refer this link where solution is mentioned in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65217081/14605502)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that there is one of your columns that has all zero values, that is why it fails at the inverse transformation. I encountered this problem and that is how I fixed it, by removing the column with all zeros.

Answer (score 0):

check for columns with entire values equal 0

```
zero_cols = [ col for col, is_zero in ((df == 0).sum() == df.shape[0]).items() if is_zero ]
zero_cols
```

the simply drop these columns